# Professional use of former MIT licensed sofware

Tags: licensing, mit-license

I'm currently working on a commercial application using a piece of software registered under the MIT license.

Recently, the author of this software removed every entry from Github, for an unknown reason (he didn't provide any details).

What are the implications on my side ? Will I still have the right to use the version of the software I currently have ?

Could there be any reason that would prevent me from using it ?

If the software license was changed to a commercial one, I understand that I could still use the version I have, but obviously not the new versions unless I pay for that.

But what if the author suddenly didn't want to share this software any more, or worse (just making wild assumptions), if some of his code was plagiarized ? What would be the implications ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you received a copy of the software under the MIT license, you still have a license to do everything that the MIT license allows you to do - "use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software". It doesn't matter if the author changes the license on future versions or even removes existing versions - the license takes affect when a copy of the software is obtained.

However, since you don't know why the software was pulled - maybe it has significant issues in it that won't be fixed and the author doesn't want defective software in the wild, or maybe you're right and the software wasn't owned by the person who released it. Depending on what kind of software you're making, you may want to look for an alternative software package or consult a lawyer to understand the risk of continuing if the software was improperly licensed.